# Confusing event emitter / closure pattern for process.on('uncaughtException')

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok this is a bit confusing so stay with me here

I have a worker, which is Node.js `child_process` started with `fork()`

The worker receives messages from the parent process, does some work, and then sends back a message when it's done. My goal is to have all my code for the worker inside the `process.on('message')` handler, so that I can use the power of closures in JS. However, my question is, when the message/data gets processed, I want to remove the listener, the `onUncaughtException` function. But will this remove only the correct function?

```
   const assert = require('assert');

    process.on('message', function (data) {

        var workId = data.workId;

        assert(workId);  //workId is an integer greater than 0

        process.on('uncaughtException', onUncaughtException);


        function onUncaughtException(err) {

            process.removeListener('uncaughtException', onUncaughtException);  //<< this removes the listener, but will it remove only the correct function?

            process.send({
                msg: 'fatal',
                error: err.stack,
                workId: workId
            });
        }


     //some more functions exist done here to do work, but I omit them for clarity's sake
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "remove only the correct function"?

Comment: so everytime on message is called, it will create a new onUncaughtException function declaration and will also create a new handler for the on('uncaughtException') event - I just want to make sure I stop listening for uncaughtExceptions as soon as the message gets processed

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it remove `correct listener` - `emitter.removeListener(event, listener)` remove listener by reference:

**index.js**

```
var f = require('child_process').fork( './worker.js' );

f.send(0);
f.send(2);
f.send(11);
f.send(8);
f.send(11);
f.send(10);
f.send(11);
```

**worker.js**

```
process.on('message', function (index) {

    function listener() {
        return index;
    }

    process.on('listen', listener);

    if (index>10) {
        process.removeListener('listen', listener);
        var index = process.listeners('listen').map( function(f) {
            return f();
        });
        console.log( index );
    }

});
```

**output**

```
[ 0, 2 ]
[ 0, 2, 8 ]
[ 0, 2, 8, 10 ]
```

Comment: thanks, do you happen to know how javascript knows this is the correct function? In other words, how does JS uniquely identify a function?

Comment: Function `onUncaughtException` is a `Function object`, in other words - `onUncaughtException` variable is a pointer to an instance of the function created each time the event `message` is called. P.S. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions